# Submitting a value of input without form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a website game and currently I am struggling with something I will name "dialogue".

Initially I tried to approach this by creating a form element, but clicking enter or submitting it ended up with page refresh, which ruins everything.

So I used inpute type text without form that looks like this:

```
You are 
<input type="text" id="dead">
<input type="submit" onclick="dead()">
```

and dead function looking currently like this, later it's gonna check for certain value, and if the value is true it's gonna run another code:

```
var talk = document.getElementById("dead").value;

function dead() {
alert(talk);
}
```

And I don't know how to save input from a form so it would be detected by JS and then used as variable in boolean check. How can I solve this problem? If there is a way to use a form tag without refreshing the page that could also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the submit event of your form like this:

```
document.getElementById('yourFormId').onsubmit = function(e) {
    // your code goes here...

    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the default operation of your form within this event
    return false;
}
```

Or create a function:

```
function handleForm(e) {
    // your code goes here...

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

And add this to your form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return handleForm(this);">
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! Could you only explain what exactly happens when you put "e" in the function brackets and then e.preventDefault(). Why "e"? Could it be anything? I assume preventDefault() is an existing function within JS.

Comment: `e` is just a parameter which you pass to the callback function and use it later in the function body. `e` would be short for event. Of course, you can use ie. `event` instead, or anything you want if it's not a [JavaScript reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm).

Answer (score 0):

To be able sending some value without refresh the page you can use Asynchronous JavaScript + XML (AJAX) and if you're working with pure Javascript without some frameworks you can see a good documentation about [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).
But of course I suggest to use some frameworks like [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make your works more easier

Comment: Im trying to polish my skills now without using more frameworks and libraries.